# Using xcopy with wildcard character

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a requirement of copying few files in to a folder. I am not sure what the folder name will be but I am sure that the folder will be ending with -Distribution.

I have written a command:

```
xcopy D:\config.dat D:\All_Dist\basic_dist\*-distribution\/R
```

But I am getting an error message as:

```
File creation error - The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /d /r "D:\All_Dist\basic_dist" %%a in (*-distribution) do (
    copy "d:\config.dat" "%%~fa"
)
```

Search for the required folder, then copy the file into it.

Comment: This does not have a wild card in the source directory. And he is asking for xcopy not copy.

Comment: @Marichyasana, to copy a single file, no need for xcopy, but this can be used. The question does not involve any wildcard character in source, only in target. And this is what can not be done not with copy nor with xcopy and the reason for the `for` command.

Comment: no problem, but the title does say xcopy, and I thought there was a comment from the OP about wild card on the source side, maybe I was just up too late. Also curious as to why you use /d instead of /f

Comment: @Marichyasana, `for /f` with a dir command needs to read all the structure before starting the process. `for /r` will recurse from the indicated folder processing elements as they are found, and `/d` ask to only report folders, not files. Up to this point, both options should work, but the `for /f`+`dir` needs an aditional instance of `cmd` that runs the `dir` command. So, in this case, the `for /d /r` "maybe" could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Since my directories and files are named differently from yours, I tried to match what you are trying to do and I got this to work.

```
xcopy low\javadeployreg.* \Users\Philip\appData\Local\temp\*-Dist /R/Y
```

However, if I include the last backslash after the "*-Dist" I get the same error as you but with the added information **Unable to create directory - C:\Users\Philip\appData\Local\temp*-Dist** so it looks like you just have to remove that last backslash.

the /Y is needed or you will get a prompt for each file you attempt to overwrite a file.

Comment: Test this again - it fails here.